# Dealing with linter errors caused by dynamically adding parameters to decorated functions

Tags: python, python-decorators, pylint

The below (simplified) code works FINE. In a nutshell: the dynamic argument passed to my function is used by the decorator and NOT the decorated function. But I get this annoying Pylint error ("*Too many positional arguments for function call*"). **I know I can disable this error in my IDE / Editor settings (or using pylint's inline disable option)**. I also know that there are other solutions that produce other linter warnings (example: unused argument, etc.).

**Bottom line:** it would be great if I could figure out, once and for all, the most "Pythonic way" of writing this in a way that doesn't upset the linter.

```
def my_decorator(func):
    ''' dummy decorator '''
    def wrapper(incoming_data):
        if incoming_data['flag']:
            # run the decorated function (NO ARGUMENTS needed):
            return func()

         # run some other code
        return "I did something ELSE"

    return wrapper


@my_decorator
def do_something():
    ''' dummy function '''
    return "I ran the decorated function"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_data_1 = dict(flag=True,
                     not_needed="useless_data")
    result = do_something(my_data_1)
    print(result)  # "I ran the decorated function"

    my_data_2 = dict(flag=False,
                     not_needed="useless_data")
    result = do_something(my_data_2)
    print(result)  # "I did something ELSE"
```

Comment: I don't understand. Neither the decorator nor the decorated function have any parameters. Which function call supposedly has too many positional arguments? **Edit:** I see, the wrapper has *one* parameter which is *more* than the function it wraps has.

Comment: the decorated function 'do_something()' is being passed an argument (my_data_1) which is needed by the decorator.  To achieve that, the wrapper() function takes that argument but doesn't pass it to the decorated function "func()". Best is to paste the above code into your editor, it'll clarify what's upsetting the linter despite the fact that the code works fine.

Comment: I would suggest to take the warning seriously and choose a different design, where `do_something` actually is defined with the same parameters as it is going to be used with. Therefore, I'm voting to close this question as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than decorating `do_something` to do, well, something else, define your *wrapper* as the main function (called `doer` below), and pass an appropriate function as an argument to be called when needed. `do_something` can be the default callback.

```
def do_something():
    return "I'm the default callback"


def do_something_unexpected():
    return "I'm another callback"


def doer(incoming_data, callback=do_something):
    if incoming_data['flag']:
        return callback()
    return "I did something ELSE"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_data_1 = dict(flag=True,
                     not_needed="useless_data")
    result = doer(my_data_1)  # Call
    print(result)  # "I ran the decorated function"

    my_data_2 = dict(flag=False,
                     not_needed="useless_data")
    result = doer(my_data_2, do_something_unexpected)
    print(result)  # "I did something ELSE"
```

Comment: The print results aren't accurate in your version. (No comment is better than a wrong comment, ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Define `do_something` with one parameter, to match how it is going to be used. No decorator is needed.

```
def actually_do_something()
    return "I did something"

def do_something(incoming_data):
    if incoming_data['flag']:
        return actually_do_something()
    return "I did something else"
```